# How to make MySQL filter using a combination of categories and tags

Tags: mysql, inner-join, multiple-select-query

I'm trying to make a 2-step filter to sort products using product categories and product tags.

One product can have several categories and several tags.

But, only one category can be selected at the time. After the the user have selected a category I only want to display the tags which have products in the selected category.

For example:
**INPUT**
Category = Car
**OUTPUT**
Tags = BMW, FORD

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE product(
    id INT auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tags(
    id INT auto_increment primary key,
    tag_name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE product_tags(
    id INT auto_increment primary key,
    tag_id INT,
    product_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE product_categories(
    id INT auto_increment primary key,
    category_name varchar(255),
);

CREATE TABLE categories(
    id INT auto_increment primary key,
    category_id INT,
    product_id INT
);
```

I have tried several solutions, but haven't been able to make one query which displays the correct combination.

```
SELECT tags.id,tags.tag_name
FROM tags,product_tags,product_categories
WHERE product_tags.product_id IN (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM categories
    WHERE product_categories.id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM category
        WHERE id = 3)
)
GROUP BY tags.tag_id
```

Comment: Which of the solutions you tried got you closest to what you want? What was wrong with it?

Comment: SELECT tags.tag_id,tag_types.tag
FROM tags,tag_types,category
WHERE tags.item_id IN (
 SELECT product_id
 FROM categories
 WHERE category_id = (
  SELECT id
  FROM category
  WHERE name = 3)
)
GROUP BY tags.tag_id

Comment: Are there hundreds of permutations?

Comment: I think product_categories and categories table names are interchanged; and it is confusing. Give table data and and your desired resultset in a tabular fotmat, then only I can write a proper query.

Comment: I changed the names of the tables in question to simplify it, and copied my original query by mistake.

Heres the query with correct tablenames.

SELECT tags.id,tags.tag_name
FROM tags,product_tags,product_categories
WHERE product_tags.product_id IN (
 SELECT product_id
 FROM categories
 WHERE product_categories.id = (
  SELECT id
  FROM category
  WHERE id = 3)
)
GROUP BY tags.tag_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select 
distinct(t.tag_name)
from tags t
join product_categories pc on pc.category_name = 'Car'
join categories c on c.category_id = pc.id
join product_tags pt on pt.tag_id = t.id and pt.product_id = pc.id
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be working fine

```
select disticnt t.*
from tags t
join product_categories pc on pc.category_name = 'Car'
join categories on c.category_id = pc.category_id and c.product_id = p.id
join product_tags pt on pt.tag_id = t.id and pt.product_id = p.id
```

Comment: I want to output the tags which have products in the selected product category. It looks like that query will output a list of the products where the tags are already known/set

Comment: Then you can swap tables product with Tags.

Comment: Thanks. I assume you meant to write t.id and not p.id. Unfortunately I get 0 results when i run the code. But I think its very close to what I need.

Comment: @sdfgg45 : strange, questioner got clue and you said not even close :(

Comment: supose its needed to actually do a demo test,andf then make the correct statment.